# regexp in php str_replace

Tags: php, regex

I want to use a regexp in my `str_replace`, i suppose the correct solution to this would be to use `preg_replace` but i don't know how to use that.
Anyway i want to turn `src=` into the character `a` if it matches `src=` or if it has any spaces in between `src` and `=`.
Normally to just turn src= it'd be:

```
$string = str_replace('src=', 'a', $string);
```

But the problem is that wouldn't work when there are space(s) between src and =. This is why i need to use a regexp.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: That's why http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php exists :) For future reference, always remember to Google first, a query for `regexp in php str_replace` will take you right there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace('/src\s*=/i', 'a', $string);
```

What that RegEx means is "*match src followed by 0 or more spaces followed by =*".

Comment: if there is no whitspace, this fails. use `*` instead of `+`. Second, `=` is no special char, so no escaping required.

Comment: @dognose Corrected it.

Comment: @Campari Nice, just one more tweak. How can i make src case insensitive?

Comment: @BobSm Sure. The `i` modifier at the end makes the RegEx case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace just works as str_replace:

```
$new_string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $old_string);
```

The pattern in your case would be `"@src\s*=@i"` (`\s*` covers zero to infinite whitespaces, `@` is just one out of different possible delimeters the pattern requires, `i` (after the last delimiter) makes the pattern case insensitive.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_replace` and the following pattern:

`src(?:\s+)?=`

Split this up:

- `src` obviously finds the "src" part
- `(?:\s+)?` finds 0 or more space(s)
- `=` to finish it off, finds the "="

So altogether, it would be:

`$new_string = preg_replace("/src(?:\s+)?=/i", 'a', $string);`

Hope this helps!